# What is an OEM SSD for Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, hardware-recommendation

I have a Macbook Pro 13" Retina Display (Early 2015). I only have 128 GB of storage. I'm thinking of upgrading it. I've seen a lot of articles about purchasing OWC or Trascend's drives; however, I have not seen any article about purchasing OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) drives. I found some on eBay -- they are just a lot more expensive!

Is there something I'm missing? Do people not recommend them because of price, or because they are not really original?

If I buy one of these drives, can I hook them up to my MacBook just like I would a Trascend or OWC Aura drives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OEM means [Original Equipment Manufacturer.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer)

Manufacturers (like Apple, Microsoft, Ford, etc.) don't actually make every component in the devices they make.

For example, Apple doesn't actually make the memory, the screen or the SSD that's inside your MacBook.   They are made by other companies like Samsung, Micron, and LG.

When you purchase an OEM product (i.e. a drive), you're purchasing the same component that would have been installed.

What you are seeing on eBay are usually "pulls" from salvaged machines.  The drive they pull from a salvaged MacBook Pro, for example, will be listed as the OEM drive.

They are usually more expensive because there are very few 3rd party options avilable (i.e. Samsung doesen't offer PCIe SATA drives with the Apple spec or LG doesn't offer "Retina" quality displays elsewhere; usually all by contract)

Comment: So basically the only way to get the original hard drive is to buy a "pull", because Samsung does not offer the hard drive separately? And, are these pulls a better option that third-party hard drives?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can buy a new one from an Apple authorized service center, but the prices are prohibitive. As for 3rd party, there’s not many because the market for Apple proprietary SSDs  is very small.